# Faster alternative to eval?

Tags: performance, perl, eval

I'm dealing with a web app that uses a home-grown templating system that lets Perl code be embedded in HTML. These statements are executed by the template parser at run-time using `eval EXPR`.

This is very flexible, but these statements are scattered everywhere, and get executed a *lot*. `eval EXPR` (as opposed to `eval BLOCK`) requires Perl to fire up the interpreter each time, and my profiling reveals that they're a reasonably significant source of slowdown.

Many of the embedded Perl statements are very simple. For example, a template might have a line like this:

```
<p>Welcome, <!--E: $user->query('name') -->.
```

Or:

```
<p>Ticket number <!--E: $user->generate_ticket_number() --> has been generated.
```

That is, they're just calling object methods. There are more complicated ones, too, though.

I'm hoping to optimize this, and so far have two ideas, both of which are terrible. The first is to rewrite all templates to replace simple calls with tokens like `USER:NAME` and `USER:GENERATETICKETNUMBER`, which the parser could then scan for and invoke the appropriate object method. But then instead of dealing with templates that mix HTML and Perl, I would have templates that mix HTML, Perl, and tokens.

The second idea is to try to parse the embedded Perl, figure out what the statement wants to do, and, if it's simple enough, call the appropriate object method via a symbolic reference. This is obviously insane.

Is there some logical solution I'm overlooking?

Comment: +1 for "This is obviously insane."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try taking an approach similar to the one that `mod_perl` uses to compile CGIs:

1. Convert the template into Perl code. For instance, your first example might convert to something like:

   ```
   print "<p>Welcome, ";
   print $user->query('name');
   print ".\n";
   ```
2. Wrap a `sub {` ... `}` around that code, along with some code to unpack arguments (e.g, for things like `$user` in the sample).
3. `eval` that code. Note that it returns a coderef.
4. Call that coderef repeatedly. :)

Comment: A related approach would be to write the generated code to a `.pm` file and then load that module.  That way, the template would only need to be reparsed when it changes.  Which way is better depends on details of how the app is implemented.

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant! It lets me fix the problem without having to rewrite a gazillion templates. I will try it out, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You might take a look at [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us). It has a [templating engine](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aTemplate) which allow a syntax close to what you are using. You could possibly switch to use it or look at its source (click source on left of previous link) to see if you can draw some ideas.

FYI the Mojolcious templating engine's syntax allows the following forms intermixed with HTML appropriately

```
<% Perl code %>
<%= Perl expression, replaced with result %>
<%== Perl expression, replaced with XML escaped result %>
<%# Comment, useful for debugging %>
<%% Replaced with "<%", useful for generating templates %>
% Perl code line, treated as "<% line =%>"
%= Perl expression line, treated as "<%= line %>"
%== Perl expression line, treated as "<%== line %>"
%# Comment line, treated as "<%# line =%>"
%% Replaced with "%", useful for generating templates
```

Comment: Thanks! As I posted to Josh, I'm hoping to avoid having to replace the whole templating system, just because it's a 10-year-old piece of software and those are hard to modify. But I have heard good things about Mojolicious.

Comment: I totally understand! Still perhaps its code might help you with a few ideas.

Comment: @JoelBerger everywhere else this question would get a "Idiot use CPAN" response. +1 for being awesome my friend.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the guts of [Text::MicroTemplate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aMicroTemplate). Realistically, you might want to *use* Text::MicroTemplate, as it likely fits your needs. It builds a subroutine that concatenates strings as needed, much like duskwuff suggested. Here's the result of `build_mt('hello, <?= $_[0] ?>')` in `re.pl`:

```
$CODE1 = sub {
       package Devel::REPL::Plugin::Packages::DefaultScratchpad;
       use warnings;
       use strict 'refs';
       local $SIG{'__WARN__'} = sub {
         print STDERR $_mt->_error(shift(), 4, $_from);
       }
       ;
       Text::MicroTemplate::encoded_string(sub {
         my $_mt = '';
         local $_MTREF = \$_mt;
         my $_from = '';
         $_mt .= 'hello, ';
         $_from = $_[0];
         $_mt .= ref $_from eq 'Text::MicroTemplate::EncodedString' ? $$_from : do {
           $_from =~ s/([&><"'])/$Text::MicroTemplate::_escape_table{$1};/eg;
           $_from
         };
         return $_mt;
       }
       ->(@_));
     };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am hoping to escape from this without having to replace the current templating system, as that would be a fairly huge job. But if it becomes too much trouble, I will look at MicroTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using 'eval' to call methods in your template. Sorry to sound harsh but the point of a separated view is to remove the processing code from the view layer. The template systems described above along with Template Toolkit just pass in an object / hash so you can access it.

why not pass $user as a hashref like:

```
$user = {
        'name' => 'John',
        'id' => '3454'
      };
```

this will allow you to access 'name' with:

```
$user->{'name'};
```

Otherwise, it's likely that you have that you're doing something like:

1. template calls $user->query();
2. method calls DB to get value
3. method returns value

That's soooo much more expensive to make a database query than to pass the hash/object reference to the template. You may want to check out some code profiling tools like Devel::NYTProf to see what part of the code execution is really slowing you down. I'm skeptical that the eval is bogging down your program so much that you need to optimize out eval. Sounds like the code inside eval is what is slowing you down.

Comment: I did run NYTProf, and it seems to indicate the eval itself is a significant source of slowdown. It's consuming only 5-10% of total server time, but it's also the single biggest point. It's not really viable to replace $user->query($value) calls with $user->{$value} as the &query sub often really does do something beyond simply looking up the value. Also, that's just one call among many.

Comment: parsim, why are you calling subroutines to do work at the view layer? Shouldn't all that work be taken care of before outputting the result? Maybe you need to consider building a different type of API? If you're calling due to user interaction, it's probably time for some server side calls via AJAX.

Comment: The answer is the web app does not have a MVC architecture. (Did I mention it's almost 10 years old?) The templates effectively drive the app. It would be an enormous job to change this, so I'm stuck with it.